# data.table: new column (months)

Tags: r

I would like to add a new column in data.table in order to group hourly data into months using the row number e.g. row numbers 1 to 744 = "Jul", 745 to 1488 = "Aug" etc. This seems like it should be a very simple thing to do but I am having trouble finding a solution that allows me to create the column by referencing the row number.

Comment: Please show a reproducible example You can use `c("Jul", "Aug", ....)[rep(1:12, each = 744)]`

Answer (score 0):

My preferred method of dealing with such data is to use the package `lubridate`, because it makes it really easy to work with dates of almost any format, though you could also accomplish the same results by using built-in functions and a little more work.

```
pacman::p_load(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(Location = seq(1:10), 
                 DateandTime =  seq(Sys.time(), by="hours", 
                                    length=10),
                 Value = rnorm(10))
df

df$month <- month(df$DateandTime)
df
```

Now to reference it by row index from another object:

```
newdf <- data.frame(rowindex = seq(10,1)) 

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    newdf$month[newdf$rowindex == i] <- df$month[i]
}
```

Now if you meant something slightly different then this may need to be tweaked to reflect that. That's why @akrun was asking for a reproducible example. But if you have any trouble just let me know and I'll adjust the example solution if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. It helped get me on the right track. In the end I allocated a date/time to each row using the following:

Comment: Sorry, wasn't finished, I used dt1<-POSIXlt("2011-07-01 00:00:00") oneyear<-seq(dt1,by="hour",length=8784) and added it as a column to my data frame.

Comment: @Bertie1810 Glad you found a suitable solution. Once some time had gone by you can add an answer to your own question and mark it as the solution. If I was able to provide any small help an upvote would always be appreciated, but not expected of course. :) For the record I did upvote your question but someone else downvoted and cancelled it out.